# Xml to html5 convertion? Which is the best way? Angular6 or XSLT?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xml-parsing, angular6

We have older code which uses XSLT to convert the xml to html. Also we have used JavaScript to render dynamicly.

Now we are planning to upgrade/rewrite that code to support HTML5.

Which is the best way to upgrade? Using xslt converting html to HTML5 or completely convert the xml using Angular6

Comment: Questions that ask for advice on choosing a technology are usually closed as being "opinion-based". There's a good reason for that: although objective evaluation of technologies is possible, it usually requires much more knowledge of your project requirements and constraints than it's possible to put in a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the response.